# Vue 3 no encuentra sass

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue3

Estoy tratando de agregar `primeflex` a mi proyecto con `vue 3` y al hacer las siguientes importaciones:

```
import 'primeflex/src/_variables.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_grid.scss';
import 'primeflex/src/_formlayout.scss';
etc...
```

Recibo el siguiente error:

> Failed to compile: Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Cannot find module 'sass'

Como tengo webpack 4.0 instalo:

```
npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass
```

(sacado de https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors)

y me sigue devolviendo el mismo error. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Bueno si a alguien le pasa, lo que hice para solucionar todo esto fue: instalar ``npm i -g npm-check-updates`` que es un paquete que analiza dependencias y busca la última version, luego lo corrí con ``ncu -u``. Una vez actualizado todo a la ultima version ejecuto ``npm install``. Esto actualizo todo, pero todavia faltaba instalar sass. Ahora si, ejectuto ``npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass`` y mi proyecto funciona correctamente, y reconoce archivos ``scss``. En el caso de ``primevue``, tuve que ir a todos los archivos ``.scss`` y hacer la importación del archivo ``_variables.scss``.